# Query to find nested dictionary in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have nested dictionary which i inserted in my collection

```
data={'name': {'animal': {'lion': 2, 'tiger': 1}}}
data1={'name': {'plant': {'herb': 2, 'tree': 1}}}
collection.insert_one(data)
collection.insert_one(data1)

collection.find({})
```

It is giving me the output as.

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5fabab4c959bc806cd129d6a'),
  'name': {'plant': {'herb': 2, 'tree': 1}}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5fabb0a2959bc806cd129d6b'),
  'name': {'animal': {'lion': 2, 'tiger': 1}}}]
```

I have a two list one is name and other one is token.

```
name=["animal","ocean"]
token=["fish","desert","lion"]
```

Now my query is that first i will check if name is present in our collection or not if name is not present that we simply insert dictionary in collection like this. (ocean is not present in collection)

```
data={'name': {'ocean': {'fish': 1, 'desert': 1,"lion":1}}}
collection.insert_one(data)
```

if name is present in our collection then we will check how many token is present if token is present we will increase its count otherwise it will be so for animal we will insert.

```
data={'name': {'animal': {'fish': 1, 'desert': 1,"lion":2}}}
```

My solution is that first check if the name is present in collection or not if it is present than just fetch it and update it by iterating over dictionary.
I tried to check if name is present or not by.

```
list(collection.find({"name.1":"animal"}))
```

But it is giving me empty list. What is the correct way to solve the query?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check a key exists in an object, use the `$exists` operator:

```
list(collection.find({"name.animal": {"$exists": True}}))
```